# How do I run an Angular nodejs and MongoDB crud project I have downloaded from Github on my browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

The Zipfile consists of an AngularApp folder and a Nodejs folder.

Comment: if you provide more information about the project structure or link to the repository, it would be really helpful for others to help you.

Comment: Its a simple CRUD operation with MongoDB, Express, Angular and NodeJS. The file which I downloaded from Github consists of an AngularApp folder and and a NodeJS folder. How do I run this project on my browser

Comment: Link https://github.com/CodAffection/Mean-Stack-CRUD-Operations

Comment: make sure to run `npm install` in both the folders

Comment: if it solved your problem you can upvote and mark the question as resolved.

Comment: When running ng serve on AngularApp an error is popping up "The serve command requires to be run in an Angular project, buta project definition could not be found"

Comment: execute ng serve from inside AngularApp folder. Make sure your shell path ends at AngularApp directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed [Node.js](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/node-101-install-and-get-started-with-node-js-8442dea963a4) [Angular](https://angular.io/) and [MongoDB](https://medium.com/@bmshamsnahid/install-secure-backup-restore-and-connect-mongodb-database-with-separate-user-role-in-ubuntu-3c1b15e813db)

Make sure your mongoDB is up and running.

Now go to `/Node.js` directory and run

```
npm i // install the dependencies

node index.js // run server
```

This will make your node server run on port 3000

Go to `/AngularApp` directory

```
npm i // install the depencies

ng serve // run application
```

Now your whole application should be up and running.
To open your application in the browser,

Go to http://localhost:4200/

Answer (score 0):

Go to AngularApp folder and execute the command `ng serve` in command prompt or shell, then go to NodeJs folder execute `node index.js` in separate command prompt or shell.